# How in nodejs with mongodb write function to return all elements instead of only just created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud

I want to write function in crud application, which after save element returns all elements instead of just created.

I wrote that function:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.content)
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Rule content can not be empty' });
    
    const rule = new Rule({ rulename: req.body.rulename || 'Empty Rule' });
    rule.save()
        .then(() => {
            Rule.find().then(rules => {
                res.send(rules);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || 'Some error occured while creating the Rule' }) });
}
```

I works, but how can I improve it?

Comment: Are you facing any performance issues with this code?

Comment: No, I am new in nodejs and I think that it look wierd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `async/await` instead of Promise chaining method:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.content)
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Rule content can not be empty' });

    const rule = new Rule({ rulename: req.body.rulename || 'Empty Rule' });
    try {
        await rule.save();
        const rules = await Rule.find();
        return res.status(200).send(rules);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || 'Some error occured while creating the Rule' });
    }
}
```

As you know, it doesn't change your code performance but it's more readable in a linear style instead of nested callback functions in Promise chaining.